# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable when trying to plot function

Tags: python, plot, floating-point

I'm trying to plot a line graph in Python using pyplot but I get an error, `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable` for this line of code:

```
ycoord = [math.pow(p(1-p),(i-1)) for i in range(1,51)]
```

I basically have a function `p(1-p)^(i-1)` that I need to plot a line graph with. I have an array of coordinates 1-51. And I need to get the corresponding y coordinates with that function.
I have also tried: `p(1-p)**(i-1)`, but that has not worked either.

Here is my full code:

```
def test():
    p = 0.2
    plt.figure(1)
    #create x coordinates [1-51]
    xcoord = [i for i in range(1,51)]
    #create y coordinates from formula
    ycoord = [math.pow(p(1-p),(i-1)) for i in range(1,51)]
    plt.plot(xcoord,ycoord)
    plt.draw()
    plt.show()

test()
```

Comment: You have `p(1-p)` where `p` is a `float`, what do you want to do?

Comment: In Python (and most other computer languages I know of), `p(1-p)` does not mean `p` times `(1-p)`. You have to explicitly write the multiplication operator. i.e.: `p * (1-p)`. _Unlike_ many other languages, the exponentiation operator in Python is written `**` not `^`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for multiplication in Python is not the same as you may be used to when writing math equations, you can't omit the '*' symbol.

```
p (1-p)
```

should be:

```
p * (1-p)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory,

```
 ycoord = [math.pow(p(1-p),(i-1)) for i in range(1,51)]
```

In this block p is a floating point number, not a method name. If you have a function p that you want to call from here then rename this variable p to something else or vice versa.

Also if you meant `(px(1-p))^(i-1)` [p times (1-p) to the power i-1], you should do `pow(p*(1-p), (i-1))`